# Participant getCount is too slow

Tags: civievent

I want to show how many spots we have left in an event, but it takes like 20 seconds to get the number of participants using the getCount action. What else can I do to get that number?

Answer (score 2):

What is the number of participants you have?

depending of the entity, getCount is just a wrapper around get, so it might be the issue if you have lots of participants.

I haven't looked for participants, but writing (and contributing that back to civicrm core) a custom getCount api with a simplier query that only does select count() would probably makes it way faster